# Pip doesn't want to download dependencies of dependencies from a specific private url

Tags: python, pip, gitlab-ci

I'm working on python3 and my CI is on gitlab.

I have a private server where all the pypy packages are available.

I configured my **pip.conf** file so that pip (the on from my CI pipline) point on my private repository.

The problem is when pip try to install dependencies of dependencies it tries to get packages from **pypy** ....

*Upd*. The content of `pip.conf`:

```
[global]
index = ***my _private_repo
index-url = ***my _private_repo
trusted-host = ***my _private_host
```

Comment: Where is your `pip.conf` and what is in it (replacing private URLs and passwords with some fillers)?

Comment: Hm… Looks good. Is in in the proper directory?

Comment: Yes, pip point on my private repo when it installs packages but not when it tries to install dependencies of dependencies ...

Comment: Really strange.